# using jquery to gather and total various responses

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to have a form that allows you to start with a number and slowly remove things by filling in text boxes or checking off values

I've seen this - http://jsfiddle.net/ZZX5D/ and it works as long as they are all text boxes.

```
    $(function(){           
    $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){  
            calculateTotal($(this));
        });
    });
});

 function calculateTotal(src) {
    var sum = 0;
    var sumtable = src.closest('.sumtable');

    sumtable.find('input').each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    sumtable.find(".total").html(sum.toFixed(2));

    var bal = parseInt($('input[name="baseAmount"]').val());
    var earnedAmt = parseInt($('input[name="earnedAmount"]').val());
    bal = bal + earnedAmt - sum;
    sumtable.find(".balance").html(bal.toFixed(2));
}
```

What I'd like to do is have a list of things to choose along with values associated with them, and use check boxes to include or exclude them from the running total.

Starting Amount 100.00
eggs 2
meat 3
milk 5
total remaining 100.00

so if I hit the check box next to eggs and meat, the total remaining changes to 95.00.
I want to assign values to each product, but not include them in the total unless the user checks that box.  They uncheck it and it removes it from the total.

I'm assuming that I need to change the top part of the function where it sums everything to subtract, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: In the `sumtable.find()` bit, add a check if `input` is a `checkbox`, and then check if `checked`. If it is, then add it, if not, ignore it.

Comment: Haven't quite followed the full problem just yet, but I'll just note you can shorten "$('input').each(fn(){ this.keyup(..." to "$('input').keyup(..." . JQuery is largely based on the idea of operating directly on sets of objects, rather than looping through each of them to perform those operations. But are you sure it should be keyup, and not onchange...?

Comment: So what have your tried so far? Do you have your html laid out yet?

Comment: You mention checkboxes but your jsFiddle example has none.

Comment: I started with that jfiddle as a way of learning how it interacted, and I wanted to take it a step further by adding checkboxes to it.  As for HTML, I'm using the stuff in the jfiddle for now, but I was just fishing to see if anyone had an idea of how to morph that jscript into something that would take checked values into account.  I'm just getting started with jscripting, so this is all new.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattcushing/K5szE/2/  I started working something up, but I have a feeling I am going in too many different directions.  I don't want to write this all out and find out I can use something to do this a lot more easily.  The biggest issue I'm finding with this fiddler is that the onclick isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you might go about this. Is this the kind of thing you have in mind?

HTML:

```
<div>Starting amount: <span id="starting">100</span></div>
<div> <span>eggs:</span>  <span class="amt">2</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div> <span>meat:</span>  <span class="amt">3</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div> <span>milk:</span>  <span class="amt">5</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div>Amount Remaining: <span id="remaining"></span></div>
```

And then this in your document ready function:

```
var starting = +$("#starting").text();
$("#remaining").text(starting);

$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
    var curr = starting;
    var checked = $("input:checked").each(function (item) {
        curr -= +($(this).prev(".amt").text());
    });
    $("#remaining").text(curr);
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h238Y/).

There are lots of potential improvements your might think about adding. But personally, I'd rather use a good templating or binding framework rather than directly manipulating the DOM like this.

Comment: I am open to anything really.  I'm just working on something for a friend and the solution above was the first thing I came across.  It's really geeky, but the actual project I'm working on is a character generator for Dungeons and Dragons :)  Start with certain number of build points, spend some on weapons, on skills, and on feats.  My son and his friends play and I wanted to give them something that would help track it all.

Comment: There are several different operations I want to do with this, and I am worried that I will spend a lot of time going down one road only to find I'm severely limited.  Wondering if this might be easier to do driven by a database and PHP.

Comment: I've been working on some of it, and it's starting to work, but I'm stuck.  http://jsfiddle.net/mattcushing/K5szE/2/  I am trying to change the value of one of the checkboxes if one of the sets in the top section is chosen.  It's not even hitting the function to calculate it.